# asp.net core project throwing System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

I'm new to development after some research i came to know that the visual studio throws out of memory exception when the memory exceeds more than 2GB. 
What i tried so far is

1. setting the architecture to 64 bit in visual studio by going into Tools=>options => debugging => checked run web project for 64 bit.
2. setting the default architecture to 64 bit in environment variables and setting the active alias using dnvm.
3. Setting the 64 bit in global.json as "architecture": "x64"

Note : There are no infinite loops while loading the application. Plus no large amount of data is fetched while loading.

As soon as i hit the Play button "IIS Express" the browser shows loading for 4-5 seconds and then show System.OutOfMemoryException was thrown. At same time in the output windows i see "skipped loading symbols . just my code is enabled" and lastly it shows thread has exited with code 0.

I'm using

> .net core sdk => 1.0.0-rc1-update1 and Visual Studio update 3

I'm using entity framework code first approach so i think i don't need to close the connection there i guess.
I'm out of clues what is going on I've seen other question but none worked for me. Here is the screenshot of task manager

[Task Manager Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANgmT.png)

Comment: Which version of .net core sdk you are using? Also specify visual studio version along with updates applied.

Comment: What does the code do? Whyd does the application try to use 2GB in the first place? That's NOT normal. Most likely there's a bug that creates a lot of temporary objects resulting in memory fragmentation.

Comment: All string operations for example generate temporary strings. If you try to parse a large file with `String.Split` you'll end up with a *lot* of needless objects, a slow application and a huge memory footprint. Most of the time will be wasted in garbage collection

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have a admin login basically which is not executed until the user logs in . So when its running for the first time there is nothing that is related to data. Only HomeController with bunch of views like about,contact us etc.

Comment: Another culprit is adding a lot of items to a list without specifying a `capacity` in the constructor. A list uses a buffer to hold items internally. When that one runs out, a new one is created with double the size and the data are copied over. If you try to insert 1M items one by one, you can end up with 20 reallocations.

Comment: @Noobie this doesn't say anything about what the code does. 2GB RAM means there's a leak, unless you tried to load an entire DVD file in memory

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos how to check the memory leak can you guide please? Okay what code does is once the admin logs in he can create tests for which the student will register . Student can register and then can see the test and then give the test by clicking on the test link.

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/623

Comment: @KristófTóth should i set the target sdk as rc2 ?

Comment: Yes. As I understand they fix some issues around that. But please read the issue and the linked ones.

Comment: you need to look into your memory consumption via the project . Use some memory -object mapper details getting tools  or some memory profilers for .net and see which object cause the issue

Comment: It may or may not be related to your issue, but why in the world are you still on 1.0 and an RC of 1.0, at that? ASP.NET Core 1.0 was not production-ready, despite Microsoft's best wishes. Even 1.1 was frankly not ready for prime time. We're now on 2.2 and pushing into 3.0 soon, so your app is way behind the curve. The solution to your issue may be as simple as just going to 2.2.

Comment: @ChrisPratt it was a training project that's why its still in rc 1.0. I thank you all for your feedback and suggestions i'll try migrating in to latest to see if the error is still there.

Comment: Yeah, all the more if it's a training project. You don't want to waste your time learning stuff that's already outdated.